# get Node by it's attribute in linq to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

consider this HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="45%" align="right">
      <h2>1.00 NZD</h2>
    </td> 
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      <h2>=</h2>
    </td> 
    <td width="45%" align="left">
      <h2>0.415528 GBP</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I use this code as string and convert it to a `XML` file:

```
string raw = "<table><tr><td width=\"45%\" align=\"right\"><h2>1.00 NZD</h2></td><td valign=\"top\" align=\"center\"><h2>=</h2></td><td width=\"45%\" align=\"left\"> <h2>0.415528 GBP</h2> </td></tr></table>";

XElement info = XElement.Parse(raw);
```

now I want to get `All td that have align="right"` and write this code:

```
var elementToChange = (from c in info.Elements("td")
                            where c.Attribute("align").Value == "right"
                            select c);


 Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(elementToChange.First().ToString());
```

but I get this Error:

> Sequence contains no elements

where is problem?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You look for `"td"` elements but at the top level of the node you only find a `"tr"` element. That's why you don't get any elements. Try this:

```
from c in info.Elements("tr").Elements("td")
```

Also, you should check if there are any elements in the sequence before calling `First()` (or use `FirstOrDefault()` which returns null if there is no element).

If you don't know the path and only want all `"td"` elements with that tag value, you can also use the [`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813) extension method:

```
from c in info.Descendants("td")
```

Comment: thanks it works.but consider we don't know the path. does any way exist that return all node in any path thta has a specific attribute with specific value?

Comment: @Kerezo Yes, the `Descendants` method does that. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`Elements` would give you the *immediate child elements* of the root in this case info. You need to drill down to the elements you are looking for and then extract them by the `Where` clause. In your case the immediate children are the `<tr>`s.